# Creating UI framework more like Visual studio

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-interface

I want to develop the application UI much like as VS2010 or any similar UI models. My requirements are as below:

1. Opening new project will create empty canavs.
2. When I will do add data sheet it will add new tab page in that.
3. Remaining few things I will do on that added tab page like showing charts, different types of controls etc.
4. When I will press 'Save' it will persist whatever there on UI like added tab pages and every controls on it on disk.
5. When I will open any saved project, It will recreate everything what was there on UI at the time of saving the project.
6. I will have recently open project list.

Any idea for creating how to create such UI?

Thanks,
Omky

Comment: Take a look at the SharpDevelop http://sharpdevelop.codeplex.com/

Comment: The question should be no "How" but "Why". There are so many frameworks (both good and bad) out there, that I really don't think it is good idea to create your own. Winforms you are refering to is based on many years experience with different solutions and it still have issues (Font fallback mechanism would be an example). WPF is better, but it also has its quirks (try to change language at runtime)... These were only two of possible i18n problems, I believe templating and layouting will kill you - it is really hard to implement it correctly. Good luck :)

Answer (score 3):

Maybe develop your solution over [Visual Studio SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb166441(v=VS.100).aspx)? A good sample is [AddonStudio](http://addonstudio.codeplex.com/) for World of Warcraft which is customized dev. environment for World of Warcraft addon development based on Visual Studio.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's quite easy to implement the Visual Studio-inspired UI using [DevExpress Docking](https://www.devexpress.com/products/net/controls/winforms/docking/) library for WinForms.

[image: DevExpress Docking Library - Visual Studio UI]